# Motivic cohomology and resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a singular variety and we somehow know its motivic cohomology groups. Can the knowledge of motivic cohomology help in understanding the singularities of $X$ and how to resolve them?